# In iOS, how to dynamically load a view controller using the same tab bar

Tags: ios, objective-c

my situation is:

My app need to display the views normally but when I press and call a view that will display some sensitive information, I need to be logged, so a login view need be displayed. The trick for me is: when I call presentViewController and load the view, the view is called in a modal way that hide the tab bar and I can`t access other views.

Other thing is I`m doing the check on if user is logged in viewDidAppear, is that a bad practice?

tks for any reply.

Comment: Code in `viewDidAppear` _can_ cause problems depending on how you navigate through your app. For example, if at some point you want the user to be able to push navigate to some other view controller, then when they come back they will be prompted to login again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such cases, the concept of container view controller is your friend. You have a `UIViewController` that encapsulates all the business logic, in your case, the login logic. It manages a view that, say, has a form-like structure where the user enters the data. You can add this as a child of the parent view controller (where your tabs exist). After he presses login (or something), you can remove this child view controller and continue where you left off!

No, checking in `viewDidAppear` for session validation is something that I do all the time, I think you are fine here.

**Edit**

In response to a comment. Yes, session validation `viewDidAppear` *can* cause problems. A careful application design is the key here. I personally store the login information of the user (as a user model) in `NSUserDefaults` and remove it whenever the user logs out.

Comment: Tks, I`d check this now.